# beforeinstallprompt triggers on every load

Tags: javascript, screen, preventdefault, beforeinstallprompt

Beforeinstallprompt triggers on every load. 
I have used the code here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/
I am not using the The mini-info bar which i have dissabled by calling `e.preventDefault();`

The problem is that the `showAddToHomeScreen();` is called on every load if the user does not click `addToHomeScreen`.

I want the `showAddToHomeScreen();` function to be called only every month or so by storing information about the last "canceled" click in sessions or something similar. Isn't google suppose to do this on it's own?

This i found on the following link:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/a2hs-updates

> You can only call prompt() on the deferred event once, if the user clicks cancel on the dialog, you'll need to wait until the beforeinstallprompt event is fired on the next page navigation. Unlike traditional permission requests, clicking cancel will not block future calls to prompt() because it call must be called within a user gesture.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function (e) {
    // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
    e.preventDefault();
    // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
    deferredPrompt = e;

    showAddToHomeScreen();
});

function showAddToHomeScreen() {
    var prompt = document.querySelector(".a2hs-prompt");
    prompt.style.display = "flex";
    var open = document.querySelector(".a2hsBtn");
    open.addEventListener("click", addToHomeScreen);
    var close = document.querySelector(".a2hsBtn-close");
    close.addEventListener("click", function() {
        prompt.style.display = "none";
    });
}

function addToHomeScreen() {
    var prompt = document.querySelector(".a2hs-prompt");

    // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
    prompt.style.display = 'none';

    if (deferredPrompt) {
        // Show the prompt
        deferredPrompt.prompt();

        // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
        deferredPrompt.userChoice.then(
            function (choiceResult) {
                if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
                    show_ad2hs_success_message();
                }
                deferredPrompt = null;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your own session and add expire date. This is simple with ajax. This is how i did:

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/update_session_addtohomescreen',
        success: function (session_expired) {
            if(session_expired=='True'){
                showAddToHomeScreen();
            }
        },
        error: function () {
             alert("it didn't work");
        }
    });
});
```

This is wrapping the `showAddToHomeScreen();` function

View

```
@csrf_exempt
def update_session_addtohomescreen(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        number_of_days_till_expire = 1
        now_in_secs = time.time()
        if not 'last_session_coockie' in request.session or now_in_secs > request.session['last_session_coockie']+60:#number_of_days_till_expire*86400:
            session_expired = True
            request.session['last_session_coockie'] = now_in_secs
        else:
            session_expired = False
        return HttpResponse(session_expired)
    return None
```

You should though include csrf token in your request and also add the url to urls.py

Comment: It can also be controlled via client side cookies. Which might be a better idéa depending on your application.